# Character groups of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

I am trying to understand if we can define the concept of character group for the irreps of the symmetric group $S_n$. Considering a few examples like the character tables of  $S_3$,   $S_5$, and $S_6$ it looks to me that the collection of the elements of the character table of a symmetric group misses at least the closure property if the group operation is multiplication.

**Can I assume the followings:**

- it is not possible to construct a group from the elements of the character table of a symmetric group?
- it is not possible to construct a group from the elements of the character table of a symmetric group with the operation as multiplication modulo some integer?
- it is not possible to construct a group from the characters of a given representation of a symmetric group?
- it is not possible to construct a group from the characters of a given representation of a symmetric group with the operation as multiplication modulo some integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helas there is no way to construct a group structure on characters/representations. If you know that the image of the identity by a character is the dimension of the representation, e.g. $3$, how would you define a representation on a vector space of dimension $1/3$ ? The good news is that the set of characters can be turned into  a ring. See [ring of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_ring#Characters) for more details.

Comment: why do I need to define a representation on a vector space of fractional dimension?