# Character groups of $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

This question is supplement to a previous question, [Character groups of $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064015/character-groups-of-s-n).

Apparently, the [arguments](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2065002/48224) for not having a character group for $S_n$ is also applicable for dihedral groups to not have character group.

I would like to confirm if my observation is true. Thanks.

Comment: The same reason applies whenever the group has an irreducible representation whose degree is greater than $1$.  This is equivalent to the group being nonabelian.

Comment: When we only consider the character table (i.e. *irreducible characters*) only the degree one characters form a group (with pointwise multiplication as the group operation). For a general group $G$ those are exactly the irreducible characters of the quotient group $G/[G,G]$. When $G=D_n, n>2,$ this quotient group is either cyclic of order two or the Klein four group - according to whether $n$ is odd or even.